# get a month from the json objec using amount

Tags: javascript, json

I have one variable which is store diff. `amount` like `147421`
and i want to find with this amount want to display there `month` from `JSON`

My JSON Object looks like this:

```
var array = [
    {
        amount: 12185,
        month: "JANUARY",
        year: "2010"
    },
    {
        amount: 147421,
        month: "MAY",
        year: "2010"
    },
    {
        amount: 2347,
        month: "AUGUST",
        year: "2010"
    }
];
```

How can I do this?.
Select month where `amount == 12185`

Comment: I could not understand your question. Do you want to display the Month corresponding to a given amount?

Comment: very unclear. please explain

Comment: Are you trying to implement lookup function? Say, given the amount="147421", find all records in the array, having such amount?

Comment: @W.K.S yes i want Month using amount

Comment: @akhikhl yes. like this. select month where amount = 12185

Answer (score 6):

You can filter data using `.filter`

```
var result = array.filter(function(item) {
    return item.amount == 12185;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wnPeN/)**

Comment: Wow! I'd never heard of this filter method! 1 up :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function like this; though the array would have to be global.
Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q5qN7/).

```
function getMonth(amount){

    month = "";

    for(i = 0;i<array.length.i++){
        if(array[i].amount === amount){
            month = array[i].month;
            break;
        }
    }

    return month;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A3HuM/)

```
var result;
var your_value=12185;
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++)
{
    if (your_value == array[i].amount)
    {
        result=array[i].month;
        break;
    }
}
alert(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

try using filter

```
function getMonth(a)
{
    var j = array.filter(function(i)
            {
               if(i.amount === a)
               {
                  return i.month;
               }
            });

    return j[0].month; // here we get first matched result
}

var res = getMonth(12185);
```

res  will contain JANUARY here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Dynamic code

```
 <div><input type="button" value="12185" class="className"/>
 <input type="button" value="147421"  class="className"/>
 </div>

for (var i in my_object) {
    var cur = my_object[i];
    $('input[value=' + cur.amount + ']').each(function() {
        var msg = 'Sales Month: ' + cur.month + ' Number: ' + cur.year;

        $(this).parent('div').append('<div>' + msg + '</div>');
    });
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jeyashri/HdgmN/3/